# hw_ptr and app_ptr is not updating in alsa driver

Tags: linux, alsa

My ALSA driver implementation is given below:

1) Waiting for MSI PCI interrupt from the device.(Interrupt indicates audio data is ready to be transferred from device)

2) On receiving the interrupt, ALSA driver copies one frame of audio data to ALSA framework.

3) ALSA driver updates hw_ptr after one frame is copied to ALSA framework. The snd_pcm_period_elapsed() is called in ISR after one frame worth of data is copied.

4) Updated hw_ptr can be observed by executing the below command.
cat /proc/asound/card2/pcm0c/sub0/status

/* output */

state: RUNNING

owner_pid   : 2323

trigger_time: 114.467323430

tstamp      : 0.000000000

delay       : 7200

avail       : 7200

avail_max   : 7200

hw_ptr      : 7200

appl_ptr    : 0

where card2 is aforesaid PCIe card instance.

5) Goto step 1

Question are:

1) hw_ptr and app_ptr some times not getting updated when I start the application(for instance VLC).

2) snd_pcm_ops trigger callback is getting called in the driver when application sends "start" command. But ALSA driver is stopping by itself after one frame is copied to ALSA framework, without waiting for "stop" command.

Any inputs regarding above queries will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Kulkarni.

Comment: The hw_ptr is whatever your pointer callback returns.

Comment: @CL, my pointer function is give below.  Can you please tell me, why hw_ptr is not updating every time ans it is updating only for some time.  because of this i don't get audio in VLC application.                                                                                                                 
static snd_pcm_uframes_t  pcm_pointer(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream)                     
{
        struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
        card_driver *card_drv = runtime->private_data;
        return bytes_to_frames(runtime, card_drv->buf_pos);
}

Comment: Apparently, `buf_pos` does not update.

Comment: How do i make sure that, buf_pos get updated ? Do I need to take care extra condition as snd_pcm_period_elapsed() ?

Comment: That's your driver's responsibility. And that kind of debugging cannot be done on SO.

Comment: I will try to debug why buf_pos is not updating in alsa driver. Any idea on queries number 2 in my post.

Comment: Even though buf_pos is updated in pointer function, but hw_ptr is not getting updated.